# Vagrant: how to make one VM find another VM by name

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have an environment built with vagrant. Basically a database VM, and a webserver VM (both Ubuntu server 14.04). When the webserver is at the end of the provisioning, I'd like to run some migrations (database changes) on the database VM. The problem is, my django App is configured with a name for the database server rather than an IP. Is there anyway I can make the webserver VM see the database VM without having to explicitly set it's IP?

Here is the only solution I've found so far:

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    db.vm.hostname = 'db'
    # Notice the IP is fixed. I rather not want to do it this way
    db.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.147", bridge: "wlan0"

    db.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb| 
      vb.memory = "512"
      vb.cpus = 1
    end

    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "playbook_db.yml"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web.vm.hostname = 'web'
    web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000

    web.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb| 
      vb.memory = "512"
      vb.cpus = 1
    end

    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "playbook_web.yml"
    end
  end

end
```

**playbook_web.yml**

```
---
- hosts: web
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
  ...
    - name: Adding DNS resolution for 'database' ...
    shell: sed -i '1 i\192.168.1.147   database' /etc/hosts
  ...
```